# How to customise hamburger menu in v7 Navigation Drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Apparently v4 api looks like this

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

But it has been depreciated in latest SDK.  The new v7 API has constructor like this

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

There is no parameter which takes in custom drawable resource file (Hamburger menu). How can I customize it? I tried setting navigationIcon of the toolbar but it kinds of disable navigation drawer itself. (Nothing happens when you click it).

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to just set an `OnClickListener` on the Navigation Icon, and handle the drawer opening and closing there. Otherwise, you'll need to either subclass the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class, or use reflection on it.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try. It gave me hard time. I want to avoid using old api.